# Android : ArrayList not get cleared

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am sending arrayList from activity to subacitvity using intent.In Activity from where i am sending intent,the size & items of arrayList are correct. code is

```
  intent.putStringArrayListExtra("IMAGE_URLS", imageUrls);
```

when i hit back button and again send arraylist to subAcitivity it sends correct arrayList. But in subActivity arraylist "**image**" contains previous items though i am creating it with "new" every time.

```
 @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            load_image();
        }

        private void load_image() {
                **image = new ArrayList<String>();**
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
                image =  b.getStringArrayList("IMAGE_URLS");

                    for (int i = 0; i < image.size(); i++) {
                    infoLog("URL--->>"+image.get(i));
                }

             }
```

I also tried to **image.clear();** in back button.

```
OnClickListener backButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            image.clear();
                    finish();
              }
  }
```

it didnt worked.I didnt find the reason. please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ArrayList` returned by `b.getStringArrayList(...)` is not necessarily the *backing* `ArrayList`, it's most likely a copy. In other words, modifications to the returned list does not affect the list stored in the `Bundle`.

I suggest you do

```
b.putStringArrayList("IMAGE_URLS", new ArrayList<String>());
```